# Is it possible to create a button like this in Zurb Foundation?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

Does Zurb Foundation have a way of creating a button like the following screenshot in the topbar?

Here is my current code:

```
<nav class='top-bar' data-topbar=''>
  <ul class='title-area'>
    <li class='name'>
      <h1><a href="/">My Site</a></h1>
    </li>
    <li class='toggle-topbar menu-icon'>
      <a href='#'>Menu</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <section class='top-bar-section'>
    <ul class='right'>
      <li><a href="/tools">TOOLS</a></li>
      <li><a href="/about">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li><a href="/contact">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</nav>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That can be done in any framework rather easily

```
.top-bar ul{list-style-type:none; }
.top-bar ul li{display:inline; padding:0px 15px;}
.top-bar ul li a{padding:10px 10px; text-decoration:none}
.border{border:3px solid #111}
```

See [***DEMO***](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iGtse/?editors=110)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's quite simple. Either you need to use the existing button() mixin. An example can b found [here](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/buttons.html) or you need to just write a custom button css class.